# How to create multiple nivo slider blocks in drupal 7?

Tags: drupal-7, block, nivo-slider

I want to create multiple nivo slider blocks in drupal 7. By default there is just a single nivo slider block available on enabling nivo slider module?

Answer (score 4):

You can create multiple nivo slider blocks using [MultiBlock](http://drupal.org/project/multiblock) module. But you cant have different slides or different settings for that block as it is a copy of that block

Comment: but then there is no benefit to create copies of same block

Comment: then you can use views nivo slider